# Is there a limit on how many pipes I can use?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, command-line

So I asked a question before that added a prefix to a ping. (My last questions) that left me with the following line:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep time=
```

And this works GREAT. I have only one problem I can not get this to save it in a file. I tried it with just a simple redirect like so:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep time= >> googleping
```

But nothing gets saved in the file...

Then I tried this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep time= | tee -a googleping
```

with tee to print it on screen and also save it in the file... no luck again.

(But tried `echo hello | tee -a googleping` and it worked fine...)

So and then I tried another while loop like so:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep time= | while read line; do echo $line; echo $line >> googleping; done
```

No luck again...

So is there a limit on how many pipes and redirects one line can have? And if so is there a way that I can still achive my goal of logging when I can't reach google (I just tested it with `grep time=` to have garuenteed output and will use `grep -v time=` to get all lines that have no time in them no matter waht the error may be)

So to add is that in the end I want to do in in the mac terminal, but I tried it on ubuntu server and a mac, and neither work with any of the methodes described above.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: it works for me. Using `tee -a` means append. So if somehow you've created a file with lots of blank lines at top, your data is at the bottom. For testing, I'd recommend `tee file` or  `...> file`. If osx has `stdbuf` (I don't think it does), try adding that to the very front of your pipe list, and dbl-check how to use it with `man stdbuf`. Finally, Max pipes will be a minimum of 10-20. That shouldn't be a problem . Pluse-uno for really drilling down on your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know what magic you are using, but it does not work for me. Can you please post the exact line that is working for you?

Comment: I"m not using OSX, so I think that could be the issue. I copy/pasted your 2 versions from above. Both worked. Sorry! Did you check you ls -l `googleping` to see if the file has any size, r.e. my comment on append. Good luck.

Comment: No my file has no size, and I'm trying this on ubuntu 15.10 (I think there are more users that know ubuntu, so I'll try to get it to work there and then see if I can understand OSX...) . And I also copied my second version again. Something is off here. :/

Comment: No, this is not an OS X problem. OS X is just another Unix that behaves in very much the same way in terms of simple things like this. Pipe buffer size is usually 4KB; you won't get anything until you have accumulated 4KB of data to write. Use `grep --line-buffered` instead to flush the buffer after every line. Alternatively, use the `-c` option of `ping` to stop after sending a certain number of packets; when it stops you'll immediately get your stuff.

Comment: By the way, `stdbuf` is shipped with coreutils. I don't know if there's something comparable in the BSD world, since coreutils is always among the first few things I install on OS X.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, why I need to use `--line-buffered` with grep, but it normally outputs everything to screen with nothing behind it. And also why I don't need a simmilar option behind ping and the echo because they also write to the pipe and should therefore only give it to the next programm/command if the 4KB buffer is full. At least that is how I would interpret your answer. But thank you for the fix!

Comment: I don't understand what you said about `grep`. Speaking of `ping -c`, it doesn't need to fill the 4K buffer if it exits before even emitting 4K output.

Comment: Sorry, my first language is not english so I was maybe a bit unclear. Let me try again:  I added `--line-buffered` to grep and now it works perfectly. And I need a continued ping that doesn't stop and just records when a package is lost, or whatever other error may occur. From your explanation I got that grep would first fill the 4K pipe buffer and only then give the data to `tee` for some reason. So I would think that ping would also need to fill the 4k pipe buffer first, and only then give the data to the next line through the pipe. But that is not the case, so why is grep special?

Comment: @usbpc102 `grep` is not special. The default buffer size is 4K, but the buffering behavior can be tuned programmatically (pipe is two-way, so both sides could adjust the pipe). `grep` is written in C which is certainly low-level and flexible enough to do that. On the other hand, POSIX shells don't support buffering modifications natively, but `stdbuf` (again written in C) does exactly that, and it is capable of adjusting all three standard streams: stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Comment: By the way, you can even write a `tee` with a line-buffered mode if you'd like to. You can even write that in a high level language like python. However, for whatever reason the POSIX `tee` doesn't have such a mode, so we're stuck with this confusing scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to the number of pipes you are using. You don't see output from tee immediately because of output buffering. When grep's ouput is going to a pipe instead of a terminal, it get's block buffered. If you have enough patience, the output will appear after a while (once the buffer get's flushed).

This behaviour is implemented in the libc unless a program explicitly handles buffering on it's own. You can influence this behaviour using the `stdbuf` command:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 \
  |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done \
  | stdbuf -o0 grep time= \
  | tee -a googleping
```

I'm calling `grep` using `stdbuf -o0` which shrinks the output buffer size of grep to zero length. Alternatively you can use `-oL` which produces line buffered output.

---

Sidenote: `stdbuf` works for your example. But if you read the man page of `stdbuf` carefully, you'll notice:

> NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams  ('tee'  does
>          for  e.g.)  then  that will override corresponding settings changed by 'std‐
>          buf'.  Also some filters (like 'dd' and 'cat' etc.) don't  use  streams  for
>          I/O, and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings.

That's what I told above. `stdbuf` works only with programs which doesn't handle buffering on their own. `tee` is such a program. Meaning if you further pipe from tee you cannot use `stdbuf`.

Answer (score 17):

The [answer by hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479625/841108) explains that your particular issue is unrelated to the number of pipes.

But to answer the question in your title (*"Is there a limit on how many pipes I can use?"*), yes **there is a limit on [opened file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)**, but on current systems it is significantly big (several thousands) in practice. AFAIU, POSIX guarantee a *small* limit (perhaps only 20). Your system has probably a file descriptor limit per process, and another file descriptor limit system wide....

To set or query that per-process file descriptor limit, you might use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) and `getrlimit` with `RLIMIT_NOFILE`  (and the `ulimit` builtin of `bash`, or the `limit` builtin of `zsh`, in your interactive shell). You can also read `/proc/self/limits` on Linux (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more on `/proc/` pseudo-files). On my Linux Debian system I have 65536 maximum file descriptors per process.

IIRC, `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives the maximum number of opened file descriptors. On My system, it is 1632058 right now.

When you have reached the file descriptor limit, the [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) syscall (e.g. done by your shell for [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) with `|` ....) would fail with:

> `EMFILE` Too many file descriptors are in use by the process.
>
> `ENFILE` The system limit on the total number of open files has been
>                 reached.

And [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) can also fail for [disk quota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) excess...

> `EDQUOT`  Where `O_CREAT`  is specified, the file does not exist, and the
>                 user's quota of disk blocks or inodes on the filesystem has
>                 been exhausted.

See also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/); when programming in C, you should use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) appropriately and wisely.

Comment: Think you very much! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for in addition to get my very specific problem solved! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: This actually answers the question in the title! This is great. Thanks!