# Merging many files based on matching column

Tags: bash, awk

I have many files (I posted 5 as an example)

If there is no match with the 1st file then 0 should be appended in output

**file1**

```
1001 1 2
1002 1 2
1003 3 5
1004 6 7
1005 8 9
1009 2 3
```

**file2**

```
1002 7
1003 8
```

**file3**

```
1001 5
1002 3
```

**file4**

```
1002 10
1004 60
1007  4
```

**file5**

```
1001 102
1003 305
1005 809
```

**output desired**

```
1001 1 2 0 5  0 102
1002 1 2 7 3 10   0
1003 3 5 8 0  0 305
1004 6 7 0 0 60   0
1005 8 9 0 0  0 809
1007 0 0 0 0  4   0
1009 2 3 0 0  0   0
```

Using the below code I can merge two files, BUT how to merge all

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"0"}' file2 file1

1001 1 2 0
1002 1 2 7
1003 3 5 8
1004 6 7 0
1005 8 9 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And if `file5` has `1006 666` the output would also have `1006 0 0 0 0 0 666`?

Comment: Hi James, Yes please if it is possible.. yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 { numCols = colNr }
{
    key = $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        colNr = numCols + i - 1
        val   = $i
        lgth  = length(val)
        vals[key][colNr] = val
        wids[colNr] = (lgth > wids[colNr] ? lgth : wids[colNr])
    }
}
END {
    numCols = colNr
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in vals) {
        printf "%s", key
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%*d", OFS, wids[colNr], vals[key][colNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file*
1001 1 2 0 5  0 102
1002 1 2 7 3 10   0
1003 3 5 8 0  0 305
1004 6 7 0 0 60   0
1005 8 9 0 0  0 809
1007 0 0 0 0  4   0
1009 2 3 0 0  0   0
```

Answer (score 5):

GNU Join to the rescue!

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o auto file1 file2 \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o auto - file3   \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o auto - file4   \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o auto - file5
```

The options `-a1` and `-a2` tell `join` to insert missing fields. and the `-e '0'` tells it to replace them with a ZERO. The output is specified with `-o auto` which assumes to take all fields.

When having a large amount of files, you cannot use the pipeline construct, but you could use a simple for loop:

```
out=output
tmp=$(mktemp)
[[ -e "$out" ]] && rm -rf "$out" || touch "$out"
for file in f*; do
    join -a1 -a2 -e0 -o auto "$out" "$file" > "$tmp"
    mv "$tmp" "$out"
done
cat "$out"
```

or if you really like the pipeline:

```
pipeline="cat /dev/null"
for file in f*; do pipeline="$pipeline | join -a1 -a2 -e0 -o auto - $file"; done
eval "$pipeline"
```

*very much of interest here:* [Is there a limit on how many pipes I can use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476932)

---

**Remark:** the usage of `auto` is extremely useful in this case but not part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html#tag_20_63). It is a GNU extension which is part of the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#join-invocation). A pure POSIX version would read a bit more cumbersome as:

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 2.2 file1 file2 \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 2.2 - file3 \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.2 - file4 \
  | join -a1 -a2 -e '0' -o 0 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.2 - file5
```

More information on `man join`

Comment: Might want to clarify that `auto` is a GNU extension; if OP is using an OS that doesn't use the GNU coreutils version, that won't work. (And of course the files need to be sorted on the join field, which they are in OP's sample.)

Comment: kvantour, amazing solucion an explanation thanks a lot

Comment: The OP said she had "many files" and that 5 was just an example so maybe you could show a script to generalize the process for N files?

Comment: Great, thanks, I think that'll be much more generally useful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU awk`

```
awk '
NR>FNR && FNR==1{
colcount+=cols
}
{
for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
  rec[$1][colcount+i-1]=$i
}
} 
{
cols=NF-1
}
END{
  colcount++
  for(ind in rec){
    printf "%s%s",ind,OFS
    for(i=1;i<=colcount;i++){
      printf "%s%s",rec[ind][i]?rec[ind][i]:0,OFS
    }
    print ""
  }
}' file{1..5} | sort -k1 | column -t
```

**Output**

```
1001  1  2  0  5  0   102
1002  1  2  7  3  10  0
1003  3  5  8  0  0   305
1004  6  7  0  0  60  0
1005  8  9  0  0  0   809
1006  0  0  0  0  0   666
```

<sub>**Note:** Will work for the case mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown) and for any type of values.</sub>

Comment: multi-dimensional arrays are a GNU extension

Comment: @oguzismail Rightly said. This is just another way of doing. I am not endorsing this at all over yours :)

Comment: sjsam, tks a lot